# Как правильно оформить меню?

Tags: css3, html, css

Есть такой вариант

ПЕРВЫЙ ВАРИАНТ

```
<nav>
   <a href="">1</a>
   <a href="">2</a>
   <a href="">3</a>
   <a href="">4</a>
</nav>
```

ВТОРОЙ ВАРИАНТ

```
<nav>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="">3</a></li>
       <li><a href="">4</a></li>        
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Так вот мне человек с вебстудии пишет что ПЕРВЫЙ ВАРИАНТ что **это откровенная халтура) так нельзя) а нужно через ul li**. Почему это халтура и почему он так пишет?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Дело в том, что в языке разметки не зря придуманы различные тэги. Если в наличии есть некоторое количество элементов, схожих по стилям/принадлежности/расположению, то предпочтительно оформить их в качестве списка. А на бытовом уровне: заключая ссылку в элемент списка, мы получим дополнительную обертку, что предоставит нам более широкие/удобные возможности по оформлению этого пункта меню. Я каждый раз об этом вспоминаю, когда каждая кнопка меню красится градиентом и одновременно с этим еще и иконкой.

Comment: Дело в том, что там очень простое меню - нет картинок и градиентов, только текс

Comment: @soledar10, дело в том, что тут на вкус каждого. Нет каких-то запретов. Есть просто готовые теги, которые облегчают вам стилизацию. А меню можо сделать как угодно! Хоть дивы в ссылки вставлять. Делайте так, как вам удобней. Главное, чтоб конечный результат был приятен глазу.

Comment: soledar10, а если появится такое требование? Тогда вы будете переписывать еще и код html, вместо правок css. Предусмотрите такой вариант и последуйте рекомендации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В HTML5 правильно так:

```
<menu>
   <li>Русская кухня.</li>
   <li>Украинская кухня.</li>
   <li>Молдавская кухня.</li>
   <li>Кавказская кухня. </li>
   <li>Прибалтийская кухня. </li>
</menu>
```

В HTML4 можно так:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```